# Do NuGet config file transformations work in ASP.Net Core projects?

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, web.config-transform

I have a NuGet package that I developed, and that package contains web.config.transform file. When I install the package in a regular Asp.Net web project, the content from the .transform file is merged with the web.config (as expected). However, when I try to install the same package in an Asp.Net Core project, the web.config remains unchanged. Do config transforms even work with NuGet + Asp.Net Core?

Answer (score 1):

For similar issue there is a community created cli command at  https://github.com/nil4/dotnet-transform-xdt which allows you to transform xdt using command line.

Include above package in tools and you may trigger it post install of your package for applying xdt transform.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look. As to the original question - do you know whether config transformations are supposed to work with Asp.Net Core + Nuget, or not? I am curios whether I should correct my nuget spec or something, and try to make them work, or implement a workaround as the one you suggested?